# Eclipse proposals missing methods

Tags: java, eclipse, autofill

I have recently installed the latest version of Java, JDK 17, and the latest version of Eclipse, 2021-09. I had to do a fresh start because my previous version was bugging out, and unfortunately this one is too. The autofill/proposals is not working correctly.

For example, let's say I have a JFrame called f. I have already initialized it and I am setting it up. Originally, if I wanted to call "f.setSize()", I could just type in "f.set" and a list would pop up with that method on it. This method, among many others, no longer shows up. "setLocationRelativeTo," "setVisibleTo," "setSize," "setTitle," and some more no longer show up.

I also discovered that if I try to implement KeyListener in a class, I cannot use the shortcut ctrl + shift + o to auto-import KeyListener. Instead, Eclipse says that that interface doesn't exist and suggests to change it to MenuKeyListener.

I have looked at similar questions and videos and everyone says that it has to do with the proposals in the editor. I have checked and unchecked all of them, testing each one. No mixture of ons and offs fixes my problem.

This is a fresh version of Eclipse with no addons, plugins, or mods. I also have only made one project in the new version and have not imported any old ones, mostly because they all got accidentally deleted. I don't know why this is happening, but I can't make any more projects without having to look up the spelling and inputs for each method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Preferences-->Java-->Appearance-->Type Filters and disable all

Comment: THANK YOU. Fortunately, I learned about this a couple of days ago, I just forgot about my question. But hopefully others will now be able to find the answer.